# How do I get data from all files in CodeIgniter Multi Upload library?

Tags: codeigniter, class, upload

It took me a while to figure out how, but I got the CodeIgniter MultiFile Upload library, found [here](https://github.com/nicdev/CodeIgniter-Multiple-File-Upload), working.  The only problem is that I need to insert results into a database... File name, date, etc.  I can't figure out how to display data for ALL files uploaded.  When I dump the upload data function, it only displays the data for the last file in the array.  I haven't tried displaying the errors yet, however, I think the same problem might occur.  Is there, a way to display an array of data for ALL the files that were uploaded?  Or do I have to code one myself...  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed $_FILES in 'do_multi_upload' function..

Those are the files that you have uploaded through the input file and if you print the $_FILES you can see the image name,size and remaining all the things and after uploading the each image it gives the temp name that is the name with which the image is uploaded at the destination and you need to store that image name into database and while you are retriving that give that image name with the path that you have uploaded the images